# KnockoutJS mapping update of nested arrays "out of stack space"

Tags: javascript, knockout-mapping-plugin

UPDATE:
Trying to make a fiddle to reproduce the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/gY2JV/29/
END UPDATE

I have an object coming from the server of type DocModel.  Its hierarchy looks like this.

```
Class DocModel:
    Property Rows As List(Of DocRowModel)

Class DocRowModel:
    Property Documents As List(Of Doc)

Class Doc:
    Contains some scalar properties
```

I use it in the following viewmodel:

```
HpDocs.DocsVM = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

HpDocs.DocsVM.prototype = {
    getDocs: function (filter) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: getMethodUrl("GetDocs"),  // server call returns object of type DocModel
            data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
            success: function (response) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d, {}, self.MyDocs); // out of stack space

            }
        })
    }
};

HpDocs.dbGetDocs = function (filter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getMethodUrl("DbGetDocs"), // server call returns object of type DocModel
        data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
        success: function (response) {

            myDocsViewModel = new HpDocs.DocsVM({
                MyDocs: ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)
            });

            var bindingScope = $("#divMyDocs")[0];
            ko.applyBindings(myDocsViewModel, bindingScope);

            HpDocs.hideProgress();
        }
    })
};
```

And here's my View (the stuff inside the td is probably irrelevant to the problem - I'm just mapping a bunch of scalar properties on each Document in Documents):

```
 <table id="tblMyDocs">
                <tbody data-bind="foreach:  MyDocs.Rows">
                    <tr data-bind="foreach: Documents">
                        <td style='text-align: center;'>
                            <div data-bind="attr:  {title: Tooltip}" class='DocumentObject' runat="server" width="40px">
                                <a data-bind="attr: {href: FullServerPath}">
                                    <img data-bind="attr: {src: IconPath, alt: Tooltip}" />
                                </a>
                                <br />
                                <textarea runat="server" readonly="readonly"
                                        data-bind="html: DisplayName" 
                                        class="doclabel" rows="2" cols="10" wrap="hard"
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

When I break before knockout tries to update the viewmodel, I can see that response.d is returning the correct data in the correct format, but it runs out of stack space. 
What's up with that.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try looping through every item in the arrays and explicitly making each one observable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - I was doing it wrong.   To see what the problem was, refer to:

[knockoutJS mapping template nested arrays in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248420/knockoutjs-mapping-template-nested-arrays-in-jsfiddle)