# knockoutJS mapping template nested arrays in jsfiddle

Tags: knockout.js

I have this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gY2JV/63/

How come the data is not showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that should be changed:

```
vm = new DocsVM({
    MyDocs: ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData)
});
```

Why do the mapping here when DocsVM does another mapping?

```
vm = new DocsVM(jsonData);
```

---

Template names need to be in quotation marks:

```
template: {name: TrTemplate
```

=>

```
template: {name: 'TrTemplate'
```

---

This is not a valid binding:

```
<a data-bind="html:  'DisplayName
```

=>

```
<a data-bind="text: DisplayName
```

---

Another note: Why do you bind the event handler for the button using jQuery? Use knockout for that, for the sake of consistency.

http://jsfiddle.net/gY2JV/64/